# iPhone 11 cannot be synced. The operation timed out error post iOS update

Tags: iphone

I updated my iPhone 11 to the latest OS, and the sim card was no longer detectable. Because of this, I restored my phone on a Mac, and it now says "The iPhone "iPhone" cannot be synced. "The operation timed out."

How can I fix this?

Comment: The next thing I would try is wiping the iPhone (settings > General > Transfer or Reset iPhone > Erase all content and Settings) and then see if it will sync. Note that if it will not you'll likely need to take it to an Apple store for repairs.